# bash echo wrapper issue

Tags: bash, printf, echo, wrapper

My question is simple.

I am using some echo/print wrappers instead of simple echo calls in a bigger bash script. Example:

```
!/bin/bash
function print_common () { echo "$@"; }
function print_inf    () { echo "INFO: $(print_common $@)"; }
function print_war    () { echo "WARN: $(print_common $@)"; }
function print_err    () { echo "ERROR: $(print_common $@)"; }
```

Generally, it works very well. The below script1.sh:

```
!/bin/bash
print_err "Whoops!"
```

generates:

```
ERROR: Whoops!
```

However, script2.sh:

```
!/bin/bash
print_err "*** Whoops!"
```

generates:

```
ERROR: script2.sh Whoops!
```

The expected print result is:

```
ERROR: *** Whoops!
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Quote all `$@` to avoid globbing: `"$@"`

Comment: thanks Cyrus and stackoverflow !

Comment: @Cyrus That should probably be made an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your echo/print wrappers, wrap up a variable print_common with single qoutes

Example:

```
function print_err    () { echo "ERROR: '$(print_common $@)'"; }
```

If you don't wrap it inside quotes it will:

```
echo *** Whoops
```

And if you put a star (*) as an arguments to an echo command it will show you a list of every file inside directory where scirpt is executed.

Using quotes will show you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, rogyvoje! However, I consider the Cyrus's answer the most elegant one! Unfortunately I cannot mark a comment to be the accepted answer. Good points anyway!

Comment: This doesn't actually work. The outer function expands the arguments into the command to be run and the sub-shell then still globs them. The solution from Cyrus in the comment is correct. Moving the single quotes *inside* the `$(...)` (around `$@`)  does work however but it still less correct.